# Docker learn issue

Tags: docker

I'm learning docker with docker with get-started pages (https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#sample-dockerfile) in official docker site. In part 2 "Build and run your image" i'm trying to run docker container with next command:

`docker run --publish 8000:8080 --detach --name bb bulletinboard:1.0`

I run command `docker ps`, and there is no docker running. I tried `docker start bb` an there is still nothing. I use docker in Ubuntu 20.04 virtual machine. And thus `localhost:8000` web page "can't be reached". Docker building was successfull (i got message `Successfully tagged bulletinboard:1.0`)

Comment: What about `docker ps -a`? Doesn't it exit right after you run it?

Comment: Yes ```docker ps -a``` shows that container actually exists and exits right after it was created with code 1

Comment: try `docker logs bb` to get more info

Comment: this is my output ```npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-10-25T11_07_53_771Z-debug.log
```